# Bootstrap modal callbacks on Bootstrap 3.1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My HTML head content:

```
<link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

My js hook to modal:

```
$(\'#selectionEdit\').on(\'hidden.bs.modal\', function () {
   alert(\'close\');
})
```

My invocation:

```
data-toggle="modal" role="button" data-target="#selectionEdit" data-remote="./selection...
```

My modal declaration:

```
div class="modal fade" id="selectionEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true"
```

My problem: I didn't see my alert when I dismiss the modal.

Error in console :

[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'b.preventDefault()') hide (bootstrap.min.js, line 6) toggle (bootstrap.min.js, line 6) (anonymous function) each (jquery.min.js, line 2) each (jquery.min.js, line 2) modal (anonymous function) dispatch (jquery.min.js, line 3) handle (jquery.min.js, line 3)

Comment: Did you receive any error in the console?

Comment: [Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'b.preventDefault()')
 hide (bootstrap.min.js, line 6)
 toggle (bootstrap.min.js, line 6)
 (anonymous function)
 each (jquery.min.js, line 2)
 each (jquery.min.js, line 2)
 modal
 (anonymous function)
 dispatch (jquery.min.js, line 3)
 handle (jquery.min.js, line 3)

Comment: Why are you escaping the single quotes? `\'` should just be `'`, unless those are being escaped for server side usage?

Comment: it is printed in php script.

Comment: Resolved, when using data-remote don't forget to implement js logic on remote file. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `implement js logic on remote file.`? Thanks.

Comment: @thepriebe, you need to implement callbacks in remote file, not on caller file.